# Is it possible to speed up boot time?

Tags: android-things

On a raspberry pi 3 running R8, it takes over 30 seconds to boot up.

Is it possible to speed this up at all?

I'd like to get it under 10 seconds.

Comment: Hello Paul, I'm trying to achieve same thing with RPi3. If you already managed to reduce boot time of Android-Things on Rpi3 or you have any other work around, requesting you share the same. Thank you!